# How to move the position pointer to next line in the file using fseek

Tags: c, file

I have seen programs for file handling and in one of the program using `fseek` as shown below:

```
/* This example opens a file myfile.dat for reading.
   After performing input operations (not shown), it moves the file
   pointer to the beginning of the file.
*/

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   FILE *stream;
   int result;

   if (stream = fopen("myfile.dat", "r"))
   { /* successful */

   if (fseek(stream, 0L, SEEK_SET));  /* moves pointer to   */
                                  /* the beginning of the file */
   { /* if not equal to 0
             then error ...    */
   }
   else {
       /* fseek() successful  */
   }
}
```

Like this can one move the file pointer to the next line immediately after that line

`BO_ 377 FC_DM_MISC: 8 FC
 SG_ DATA3         m11 : 31|8@0+ (1,0) [0|0] ""  DM`

These are the two lines and I want to program in a way that when one identifies the number `377` the pointer should now go to the next line i.e., to the line `SG_ DATA3` inspite of the white spaces after `8 FC`. How can one do that using fseek in C?

Comment: `fseek` doesn't know or care what a "line" is. All it can do is move the read pointer around to a position you specify.

Comment: I need to move to the next line beginning when the number 377 has been identified... should i write my own condition to move the file pointer to the next line ?

Comment: It is unclear why you want to move a file position to the next line. If you read input with `fgets` the file pointer moves to the next line anyway. The use of `fseek` is better suited to random access files with fixed size records, than sequential text files with variable length lines.

Comment: `fseek` is really only useful if you already know your destination. If you need to scan for the next newline character that's something you'll have to do with something like `fread` or `fgets` and some parsing code.

Comment: If you are using `fseek` with a text file, you probably need a better algorithm, but the posted code is only a place holder. In particular, you don't need to seek to the start of a file when it has been freshly opened.

Comment: How can I use fgets to read line by line? I can see that as better option to be manipulated

Comment: That's all `fgets` does, read a file line-by-line.

Comment: You don't even have a buffer in your code to read to. There are a huge number of examples out there about `while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stream) != NULL) { ... }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code . It may help you .Here the Each line of the Input file is converted to *string* ,since *string manipulation* is very simple comparing to complex `fseek()` function.This may not be perfect answer but this will be very simple solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *stream;
    int result;

    char tmp[100]; // assuming that max length of a line in myfile.dat is 100.

    if (stream = fopen("myfile.dat", "r"))
    { /* successful */
        fscanf(stream, "%100[^\n]", tmp); // assuming that max length of a line in myfile.dat is 100.
        printf("%s", tmp);
        if (strstr(tmp, "377"))
        { // check for 337

            fscanf(stream, "%100[^\n]", tmp); // next line is in the string tmp .

            // continue your program.
            //printf("%s", tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`fseek` is used for binary data, if you work on a text file you should use either `fgets` or `getline`(recommended to use `getline`).

There's an open discussion of "fgets() vs getline" and many say that "fgets is deprecated" is only a gcc propaganda in favor to their specific getline().

A possible flaw in `fgets()` is that it doesn't tell you anything if there are null bytes being read, something you can get away with `getline()`.

But then again if you don't like gcc, or use something different, use `fgets()`. If you are stuck with gcc, then use `getline()`.

Comment: getline is non standard C.

Comment: @Weather Vane Edited answer.

Comment: The edit doesn't make it better. `getline()` doesn't exist in the C standard. It **was** a feature specifically of the GNU C library and now is part of the POSIX standard. There's no propaganda for anything from any side -- `getline()` is just convenient to use, but if you want full portability, don't use it. I absolutely **don't** understand your paragraph about `NULL`.

Comment: gcc does not oblige the use of `getline`. So being "stuck with" gcc allows the use of the standard `fgets`.The `NULL` returned by `fgets` tells you there was no more data. The idiomatic use is shown in my comment to the main question.

Comment: On success, getline() and getdelim() return the number of characters
       read, including the delimiter character, but not including the
       terminating null byte ('\0').  This value can be used to handle
       embedded null bytes in the line read

Comment: Why would a text file contain embedded "null bytes"? What are they?

Comment: @малинчекуров so you **mean** that `getline()` allows to read something containing `NUL` characters (that's not `NULL`, which would be a pointer). That's a somewhat questionable feature for a function dealing with *text* -- if you expect `NUL` bytes, you should probably use `fread()`.

Comment: The ordinary user is 'dumb` he doesn't know a text file cant have such a character. If you read a text file with fgets and you run into such byte, then it will break your code. As for what NULL means, im not talking in the sense of a pointer, but in the sense of a zero byte being read.

Comment: yep and this character is called `NUL`, not `NULL`. `NULL` is a standard C marco defined to the **null pointer**, e.g. `(void *)0`.

Comment: BTW, it's enough to use some Microsoft C runtime for windows and you won't have an implementation of `getline()`.

Comment: The GNU manual page says it's null, I follow what it says and it says embedded null, not nul, characters.

Comment: "*he doesn't know a text file cant have such a character. If you read a text file with fgets and you run into such byte, then it will break your code.*" this is contradicting itself. A **text file** does not contain any `NUL`s. A "dumb" user trying to read a **binary** file with `fgets()` should take a step back and learn. Being able to read binary files with `getline()` still looks strange.

Comment: If a corrupt text file can easily break your program, but hey, it's your problem if you don't want to protect yourself. After all the junior programmers won't have job to do, if not fixing some bug in production that happens to break the system because of a single corrupt text file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170434/discussion-between---and-felix-palmen).

Comment: `fgets` will in no way **break** on `NUL` bytes, so if your program breaks, you didn't validate your input. Therefore, I'm leaving this pointless discussion now.

Comment: If you use fgets to read a file with NUL characters, then the most likely result is that each lne will appear to have been truncated at the first NUL. That's not a buffer overrun and it's not UB. It might be a bit odd, but posix (at least) does not guarantee that non-text files can be handled by test utilities. Furthermore the C standard does not guarantee that NUL in text files can be read at all. So who are you defending against what?

Comment: As an example on top of my head is the Null Byte Injection  attack. http://projects.webappsec.org/w/page/13246949/Null%20Byte%20Injection

Comment: @малинчекуров this just shows brain-dead code not properly validating user input. the NUL isn't special here, just a way to exploit this crap.